# Xamarin.iOS - Publishing App - Invalid Swift Support - The files ... don’t match

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am publishing my iOS app for review but give me back error:

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   libswiftsimd.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib,
>   libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftCoreData.dylib,
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib,
>   libswiftAVFoundation.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftos.dylib,
>   libswiftMapKit.dylib, libswiftMetal.dylib don’t match
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftMapKit.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib. Make sure the
>   files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply
>   post-processing to
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftMapKit.dylib,
>   /Payload/Project.IOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib.

Publish step:

1. Build archive
2. Build ipa with need provisioning profile
3. Unzip my.IPA
4. Use the script (https://github.com/bq/ipa-packager)
5. New .ipa upload from Application Loader to App Connect

Anybody have any ideas on how to do this? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if the ipa-packager script includes the wrong version of Swift files in the 'SwiftSupport' folder it creates. This will cause the Swift versions in the .ipa (as built by VS) not to match the .dylib files in the SwiftSupport folder (as added by the script).

The solution is to install the XCode version that was bundled with the Swift version you are targetting, and then using a command like the following to switch which XCode is being used for the command line tools, before running the ipa-packager script, so that the proper version of .dylib files are put in the SwiftSupport folder:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5.1.1/Xcode.app
```